# How to make wordpress point to my custom php pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a PHP website running on example.com and I am planning to run WordPress alongside. Wordpress would also be installed on the same directory/domain (example.com) to handle front pages like the homepage, faq, contact-us e.t.c so that non-technical guys can edit their contents

I have recreated some of the old custom PHP pages as page templates in the theme folder which works fine but I want other files like games.php to work as before.

For example: example.com/games should point to games.php in the root directory and not return the WordPress 404 page. How do I go about this?

Comment: i would tag apache or nginx into this, not a php or a wordpress question

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @delboy1978uk. I was not thinking in that direction. The answer below solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requirement can be implemented using Apache (or Nginx) url rewrite rules.

For example, in the case of Apache, you would need to add something like the following configuration lines in the `.htaccess` file of the site's root directly.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^games/?$ /games.php [L]
```